# Excel doesn't simplify all fractions as expected

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm using Microsoft Excel to help with my statistics homework.

Using the fractions formatting 95% of the fractions I simplify with excel work out correctly.

However there are some fractions I have found that don't simplify correctly. (eg. when I simplify them by hand or try them in every other online fraction simplifier) This can produce wildly different answers when using formulas.

The following fractions don't simplify in excel the same as they do by hand or in any of the online ones I have tried.

```
761/1160 simplifies into 473/721 but should remain 761/1160,

291/2024 simplifies into 112/779 but should remain 291/2024,

487/1160 simplifies into 144/343 but should remain 487/1160,

1067/1160 simplifies into 218/237 but should remain 1067/1160,

399/1160 simplifies into 248/721 but should remain 399/1160.
```

Why are Excel's answers different? How can I make Excel get the answer I need every time? I understand formatting shows something different than whats in the cell, but these are the only five fractions I encountered problems on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's standard fraction number format limits the precision to which it will display fractions [(documentation here)](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Display-numbers-as-fractions-0121ecac-1773-4f2d-8cd3-7db51fd83b77).  The highest is three digits - i.e. Excel will display the nearest fraction that can be expressed with no more than 3 digits in the denominator.

It is possible to get round this by using a custom number format ([helpful reference here](http://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-custom-number-formats-excel/)).  For example, for fractions with up to four digits (plus integer at the beginning) use:

```
# ####/####
```

But you should note that internally Excel converts the fraction to a floating point number with limited precision - which often won't be exactly equal to the fraction, then converts it back to a fraction for display.  If you want to work with fractions and get exact answers, Excel really isn't the best tool to use - you need a [symbolic computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) tool (e.g. Mathematica).